# Питон не находит файл

Tags: python-3.x

После переустановки винды и питона при попытке запуска питон скрипта находящегося на втором жестком диске файл не находится, но при запуске с рабочего стола все работает. Как исправить?

Пишу в коммандную строку `cd D:\folder` затем  `python main.py`, вылазит ошибка

```
python: can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

Если делать тоже самое только на рабочем столе `cd C:\Users\username\Desktop` то все работает

Comment: Добавьте больше конкретных деталей. Так не очень понятно что вы делаете.

Comment: А именно - полный вывод консоли, как именно вы запускаете и что выводится в консоль?

Comment: пишу в коммандную строку `cd D:\folder` затем  `python main.py`, вылазит ошибка **python: can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory** . Если делать тоже самое только на рабочем столе `cd C:\Users\username\Desktop` то все работает

Comment: @Deathstroke словестная интерпретация не очень интересна. Скопируйте все, что происходит в консоли и добавьте в текст вопроса.

Comment: @Deathstroke ну а файл точно находится в той папке, из которой вы его запускаете?

Comment: сори я только сейчас заметил что проблема в другом у меня командная строка почему-то не меняет букву диска после ввода - `cd D:`

Comment: @Deathstroke `cd /d D:\path`

Comment: спасибо, а так надо будет писать каждый раз при переходе на другой диск?

Comment: @Deathstroke да, без этой опции переход осуществляется только между каталогами одного диска.

Comment: @Deathstroke не забудь отметить ответ на вопрос как решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как выяснилось [в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161631/%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb#comment2014867_1161631), проблема была в том, что автор вопроса вводил для смены пути следующую команду:

```
С:\home\path > cd D:\path\to\folder
С:\home\path >
```

и в результате не переходил на другой диск и не менял рабочую папку.

Для перехода на другой диск, необходимо ввести данную команду с опцией `/d`

```
С:\home\path > cd /d D:\path\to\folder
D:\path\to\folder >
```

---

**Еще один вариант** от [gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201445/gil9red) из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161631/%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb/1161644?noredirect=1#comment2014924_1161644) к моему ответу

```
С:\home\path > cd D:\path\to\folder
С:\home\path > D:
D:\path\to\folder >
```

Comment: А можно после ввода пути в папку на другом диске, ввести букву другого диска, например `D:`

Comment: @gil9red как будет выглядеть итоговая строка с командой?

Comment: Вариант с `/d` хороший, я о нем не знал :) А по поводу того, что я писал, выглядит так: **1)** `C:\Users\ipetrash> cd D:\Program Files` **2)** `C:\Users\ipetrash> D:` **3)** `D:\Program Files>`

Comment: @gil9red добавил твой вариант в ответ. Спасибо!